# Getting selection attribute values from a server side generated drop down with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have a select drop down generated from the server side so I cannot change it to use a javascript or array or ng-select. I would like to convert the attributes of the selection into a javascript object.

```
<select ng-model="selectedVal" ng-change="selectVal()">
    <option value="val1" attr1="attr11val" attr2="attr12val" cp-option="allObjs">opt1</option>
    <option value="val2" attr1="attr21val" attr2="attr22val" cp-option="allObjs" selected>opt2</option>
    <option value="val3" attr1="attr31val" attr2="attr32val" cp-option="allObjs">opt3</option>
</select>
```

I would like 'selectedVal' to look like this:

```
{"value":"val2","attr1":"attr21val","attr2":"attr22val"}
```

The best solution I can come up with is adding a directive to each option that gets the attributes and pushes them to an object array. I then can use ng-change on the select drop down. Then get the selected object on the array based on the selection's value.

Is there a better way to do this?

Here what directive looks like:

```
app.directive('cpOption', function () {
function link(scope, elem, attr) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var property in attr.$attr) {
        if (attr.hasOwnProperty(property)) 
            obj[property] = attr[property];
    }
    scope.cpOption.push(obj);
}

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: link,
    scope: {
        cpOption: '=cpOption'
    }
}
});
```

and the controller

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.allObjs = [];
$scope.selectedVal = {};
$scope.selecteObj = {};

$scope.selectVal = function () {
    for (var val in $scope.allObjs) {
        if ($scope.allObjs[val].value === $scope.selectedVal) {
            $scope.selecteObj = $scope.allObjs[val];
            break;
        }
    }
}
});
```

Any better ways to accomplish this? 
Ideally I wouldn't need the array with all the objects, I just need the selected object.

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ocLrt7vp/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me. I created a directive that gets the value on change. Then converts the attributes to an object.

```
app.directive('cpSelectAttrs', function () {

function link(scope, elem) {
    elem.bind('change', function () {
       getSelectionAttrs(scope, elem);
       scope.$apply();
    });

    getSelectionAttrs(scope, elem);
}

function getSelectionAttrs(scope, elem){
        var obj = {};
        var attrs = (elem[0].selectedOptions[0].attributes);
        var length = attrs.length;
        obj.text = elem[0].selectedOptions[0].text;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            obj[attrs[i].localName] = attrs[i].value;
        }
        scope.cpSelectAttrs = obj;
}

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: link,
    scope: {
        cpSelectAttrs: '=cpSelectAttrs'
    }
}
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yzLx6x7d/3/